# Does WebSockets harms the battery on android?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, sockets

I using `WebSockets` in my web application to create real-time application (My application was built using .NET MVC 5).

I want to create android application that will also connect to the same `WebSocket` to get real-time updates. Does it will waste the battery more than the old regular `socket`? And if so, how I can fix this problem without changing my old site (only adding) and without `GCM` (It goes against my company polices)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think so. WebSockets just like HTTP alone is just higher level abstraction on top of the TCP, just like many other "permanently connected" TCP based protocols - using good old sockets. I dont see any space for more energy consumption.

Comment: So how can implement `Websockets` in android?

Comment: @ZilbermanRafael 
I've used https://github.com/koush/android-websockets to connect android client to backend.